# Manifold and action associated to a central extension of groups

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, group-actions, exact-sequence, group-cohomology

Let $X$ be a manifold equipped with a proper $G$-action. Suppose we have a central extension
$$0\to H\hookrightarrow G'\to G\to 0,$$
where $G\cong G'/H$.

**Question 1:** Can one construct a manifold $X'$ on which $G'$ acts properly, with the property that $X'/G'$ is homeomorphic to $X/G$?

**Question 2:** If not, is there a topological obstruction to the existence of $X'$?

In other words, I would like to know: given a class in $\alpha\in H^2(G,H)$ and a proper $G$-manifold $X$, is there a manifold $X'$ on which the extension defined by $\alpha$ acts?

*Remark:* Since $G'$ is a fiber bundle over $G$ with fiber $H$, my guess is that $X'$ should be a $H$-bundle over $X$, but I'm not sure how to write down $X'$ explicitly.

Comment: Your question is not very well formulated. If $G$ any group $H$ with a homomorphism $\rho H\to G$ acts, by $h.x=\rho(h). x$.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for pointing this out. I'm not exactly sure how to formulate this question, although I've now changed it a bit to try to express what I mean. If $S^1$ is replaced by an arbitrary group, then action you wrote down may not be proper.

Comment: Do you have a particular example/application in mind?